How to connect to Kafka Kraft mode in Docker Compose network
I'm using Docker Compose to start Kafka and a Spring Boot application that connects to it. If I run the Spring Boot application outside of Docker then it can connect to Kafka with this configuration:
  kafka:
    bootstrapServers: localhost:9092
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: PLAINTEXT

But when I start also the Spring Boot application with Docker Compose after changing config to this:
  kafka:
    bootstrapServers: kafka1:9092

I get these to the application log:
2024-07-31 16:44:11 2024-07-31T13:44:11.109Z  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-ocs-message-observer-group-id-1, groupId=ocs-message-observer-group-id] Node 1 disconnected.
2024-07-31 16:44:11 2024-07-31T13:44:11.110Z  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-ocs-message-observer-group-id-1, groupId=ocs-message-observer-group-id] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Based on what I have found, it seems that I need to set KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS environment variable. But setting that seems to open a can of worms. The first exception indicates that Zookeeper needs to be setup. Adding other environment variables based on examples makes Kafka to start but the Spring Boot application still cannot connect to it. This is from my current compose.yaml:
  kafka1:
    image: apache/kafka:3.8.0
    container_name: kafka1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka1:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka1:29093'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CLUSTER_ID: 'ciWo7IWazngRchmPES6q5A=='
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'

What do I need to change here to make Kafka available at kafka1:9092? Is it enough to have KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker'?

You already have advertised listeners set. Did you try to use kafka1:29092?

I changed ports to 29092:29092 and made the corresponding change in Spring Boot config. Still, it's not able to connect but one of the log messages is a bit different, it shows the host name now:  Bootstrap broker kafka1:29092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected.

Solved by ChatGPT but I cannot post the solution because of SO AI policy.

29092:29092 would be from the host, not between containers. 9092:9092 is correct for connecting outside of Docker. You can paraphrase the solution in your own words? Did you need to run the Spring app from the same compose file?

I do understand the difference. i wrote the answer to that post. But there actually isn't any difference since the advertised listeners configuration is still the same between Zookeeper and Kraft mode and that's how clients are resolving any address. You're welcome to post your answer on the other post, since it was not specific to Zookeeper, and is asking how to connect clients with a kafka docker container.

Setup the listeners to 0.0.0.0, rather than the container hostname so it can accept external connections
  KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka1:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://kafka1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
 

Then run the Spring app in the same Docker network and connect to the advertised listener kafka1:29092
Note: The appropriate Spring Boot auto configuration would be spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers

Is it enough to have KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker'?

At least one controller process is required

My working solution is very simple and there I have KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,CONTROLLER://kafka:9093 and no KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS. spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers has value kafka:9092.

Your docker compose file uses kafka1 as the hostname, though, so did you change this as well?

Yes, sorry for the confusion. It was simplified for the final solution to have kafka instead of kafka1.
